# mysql timestamp column

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Is it possible to define a timestamp column in a MySQL table that will automatically be updated every time a field in the same row is modified? Ideally this column should initially be set to the time a row was inserted.

Cheers,
Don

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That is the default functionality of the **[timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html)** column type.  However, note that the format of this type is yyyymmddhhmmss (all digits, no colons or other separation).

**EDIT:** The above comment about the format is only true for versions of MySQL < 4.1... Later versions format it like a **DateTime**

Comment: According to the MySQL 5.0 docs, the timestamp type is in the same format as datetime (eg 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS').

Answer (score 53):

You can use the timestamp column as other posters mentioned.  Here is the SQL you can use to add the column in:

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD `lastUpdated` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

This adds a column called 'lastUpdated' with a default value of the current date/time.  When that record is updated (lets say 5 minutes later) that timestamp will automatically update to the current time.

Comment: The following appears to be sufficient:

ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD `lastUpdated` TIMESTAMP;

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have observed (MySql 5.7.11) -

The first TIMESTAMP column in the table gets current timestamp as the default value. So, if you do an INSERT or UPDATE without supplying a value, the column will get the current timestamp.

Any subsequent TIMESTAMP columns should have a default value explicitly defined. If you have two TIMESTAMP columns and if you don't specify a default value for the second column, you will get this error while trying to create the table -

ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'COLUMN_NAME'

Answer (score 1):

A MySQL timestamp is set with creation or update time only if their default value is set as it. `ALTER TABLE some_table ADD when TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.
Otherwise it works just like a DateTime field, only that it's relative to 1970/01/01 UTC, so it's an absolute point in time not depending on a specific timezone as is DateTime.