# Adding new Column with current time in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Im trying to add a new column to my SQL table i want the data type to be TIME and the default value to be `CURRENT_TIME`. This is my query.

```
ALTER TABLE tuesday_records ADD cur_time TIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME
```

And this is the error message i get.

```
Error
SQL query:


ALTER TABLE tuesday_records ADD cur_time TIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURRENT_TIME' at line 1
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the MariaDB documentation? https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/timestamp/

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/155096/571723

Comment: You probably want TIMESTAMP instead of TIME as data type.

Comment: What is your version? Works for me on 10.2 and 10.3 - But I still think you want TIMESTAMP.

Comment: version 10.1.38. I need to find the time difference between 2 things i can have this column as a TIMESTAMP but i need to have the other one as TIME, so if there is a way to find the time difference between TIMESTAMP and TIME that would also help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want with generated columns:

```
create table t (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    x int,
    t timestamp default now(),
    tt time generated always as (time(t))
);
```

That is, add a timestamp column and then extract the time.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=85e9ba0e5cbfae3afa4cca3c141284d0) is a db<>fiddle.

Although this answers your question, I'm not sure if it is the best approach to your overall problem.