# MySQL Workbench: Add Timestamp Fields

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Its been years since I used MySQL (ability maybe 3/10?) but I've just installed MySQL for personal interests.

I'm trying to add two Timestamp fields: 'created' and 'updated' in the MySQL Workbench - which has changed a bit from what I vaguely recall.

'created' should auto-insert date/time when a record is created, and 'updated' should auto-update the field when the record is updated.

How can I create these in the Workbench pls?

[image]

Comment: Are converting an existing `VARCHAR(45)` column or creating a new column?

Comment: I was creating a new column, and tried to select TIMESTAMP(), but Workbench won't allow it, and reverts to a default (I think).

Comment: Yeah, I think it just copies previous column (`type_name` in this case). I cant' find anything obviously wrong in your definition. Workbench has always been full of these annoying glitches.

Comment: Odd. I know I used to be able to add a 'created' column which worked automatically, but I think I had to update the 'updated' column via the program I was connected to - although I seem to recall an "ON UPDATE' column setting.   Still googling but haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Workbench used to have a separate column for `Initial Value`, rather than concatenated as they are now. Oh well, I'll get used to the new layout. The error msg could have been more informative though.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set specific precision in brackets example: `TIMESTAMP(6)`

Please check on my screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I ended up using SQL to add the columns, from a SO post ([Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155054/mysql-timestamp-column)):

ALTER TABLE `security_type` ADD `updated` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;

ALTER TABLE `security_type` ADD `created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;

However, inspecting the table definition, I see that the Type is TIMESTAMP, whereas I had selected it as TIMESTAMP() (with parentheses)from the dropdown list.  It also displays the DefaultExpression which should have been entered if adding these columns in Workbench:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is quite hard to find, but `TIMESTAMP` columns accept an optional modifier to set [fractional seconds](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html):

> MySQL has fractional seconds support for TIME, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP values, with up to microseconds (6 digits) precision:
>
> - To define a column that includes a fractional seconds part, use the syntax `type_name(fsp)`, where type_name is `TIME`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP`, and `fsp` is the fractional seconds precision.

The drop-down values include parenthesis so you can then edit the column type details (since there's no other UI for that). Empty parenthesis would trigger a syntax error on the server and Workbench seemingly fails to deal with them in a user-friendly way.

If you want fractional seconds, you must type a value. Otherwise, you need to either type a zero or remove the parenthesis altogether; in either case, the generated SQL is the same:

```
ALTER TABLE `investment`.`security_type` 
ADD COLUMN `created` TIMESTAMP NULL AFTER `type_name`;
```

Regarding the auto-update part, please check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html for the details.